# How to collect impressions with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, impressions

I would like to make some script (like some ads) to collect impressions on user site (views).

Does anyone know that works? I know that I should put some script code that should somehow send data to my website, but I am not sure what is the logic behind it? Does it sends data to another file which calls some script using Ajax or there is some easier logic?

I would like to make all from scratch and not to use Google analytics for that.

Thanks everyone for suggestions!

Comment: Why do you want to do everything from scratch? Is there a specific reason? You'll basically have to report every view (along with the user related information) to the server using AJAX and then store the data on the server.

Comment: so I send straight from the other's people site via AJAX to my server. I would like to try to make it from scratch.

Comment: assuming that the site's Content Security Policy allows it, then yes. However, normally such ads/code would be implemented in an embedded iframe rather then a dirct JS, to avoid collisions and security issues.

Comment: You can also have a look at http://piwik.org/. But I think your question is to vague and open ended for SO.

Comment: I am trying to create an ad server. So I would like to people put my js code on their page and to use it for calculating impressions. Maybe it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two recommendations:

[Open Web Analytics](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com) - an open source framework that will let you setup your own PHP server and use an out of the box JS client for reporting

[How To Create Your Own Stats Program (JavaScript, AJAX, PHP)](http://www.noupe.com/php/how-to-create-your-own-stats.html) - a good sample that will let you understand how to build a simple solution from scratch.

Comment: wow, both solutions looks interesting. I will take look on both. I think this is great answer!